# MVC view with two forms, why are both rendering to same action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, html.beginform

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Unassign", "Terminals_DataGroups"))
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DataGroupId)
    <input type="submit" value="Remove group from device" @(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.DataGroupName) ? "disabled=\"disabled\"" : "") />
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Assign", "Terminals_DataGroups"))
{ 
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DeviceId)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataGroups)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DataGroupsSelectedItem, new SelectList(Model.DataGroups, "Value", "Text"))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataGroupsSelectedItem)
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Assign Data Group" />
}
```

Yet the HTML renders as:

```
<form action="/Terminals_DataGroups/Assign" method="post">
    <input data-val="true"
        data-val-number="The field DeviceId must be a number."
        data-val-required="The DeviceId field is required."
        id="DeviceId"
        name="DeviceId"
        type="hidden"
        value="15" />
    <input data-val="true"
        data-val-number="The field DataGroupId must be a number."
        id="DataGroupId"
        name="DataGroupId"
        type="hidden"
        value="1" />
    <input type="submit" value="Remove group from device"  />
</form>

<form action="/Terminals_DataGroups/Assign" method="post">
    <input data-val="true"
        data-val-number="The field DeviceId must be a number."
        data-val-required="The DeviceId field is required."
        id="DeviceId"
        name="DeviceId"
        type="hidden"
        value="15" />
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="DataGroups">Data groups</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <select data-val="true"
            data-val-number="The field DataGroupsSelectedItem must be a number."
            id="DataGroupsSelectedItem"
            name="DataGroupsSelectedItem">
            <option value="2">DataGroup2</option>
            <option value="3">DataGroup3</option>
            <option value="5">New group</option>
        </select>
        <span class="field-validation-valid"
            data-valmsg-for="DataGroupsSelectedItem"
            data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Assign Data Group" />
</form>
```

Comment: try to add `id` field to forms.

Comment: thanks but no difference.

Comment: Your code looks good... are you doing any javascript or anything that might be retargeting your form?

Comment: Thats strange. I could see both the forms displaying their individual actions at my side. Can you check if there are any Console errors or Script errors

Comment: I created a MVC4 project, copied your view code to it, implemented a simple model to satisfy the view, and the appropriate html is generated.  I would have to say that it looks like you're either looking at old Html (try F5), or some compile error that you are not seeing.  Do you have the Build MVC Forms turn on in the project so that the forms are compiled at build time?

Comment: Hi Scott, yes its strange but i can confirm this is not a cache issue. I had an inkling it was something to do with my route table, seemed a good guess so I added a new route for the unassigned action and it works now. thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

you must added ID tag and value 
sory my english ;)